# JPanel derived class in JFrame - painting duplicate

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I've added my JPanel derived class to the JFrame. Now when I want to draw an oval (using fillOval in my JPanel's paintComponent method) I see two ovals being painted. The problem disappears when I invoke super.paintComponent or when I invoke setContentPane in the JFrame class with my JPanel as parameter. The question is, why does it happen? Of course when the upper left corner of both JPanel and JFrame are in the same place, it doesn't happen. But somehow the JPanel isn't opaque unless I invoke super.paintComponent. The main question is why does it paint BOTH on the default content pane AND my JPanel. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

> " The main question is why does it paint BOTH on the default content pane AND my JPanel."

It just appears that way, but actually you are seeing both being drawn on the panel. Always call `super.paintComponent` in the `paintComponent` method (no if ands or buts) or you *will* see paint artifacts as the one you're experiencing. The `paintComponent` method can be called for any number of reasons, and each time it's called, is another opportunity for paint artifacts to appear. Calling `super.paintComponent` wipes those out. When you set the content pane to the panel, it appears the `paintComponent` method is not being called more than once, so you don't get those artifacts. But to reiterate, always call `super.paintComponent`. Setting the content pane has nothing to do with the problem or the solution.

Comment: super.paintComponent(g) actually clears the panel, if you don't call it the newly painted stuff just appears on top of the old stuff creating those artifacts you see.